# Models not working with the new Ember-data upgrade

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, ember.js

I have set up Ember on Rails to do some practice, the data in my models were originally picked up but after the new bundle install, data in my models are not taken anymore. I think it ' because the new Ember-data gem installed.

Here the [commit](https://github.com/Mannaio/Ember-Application/commit/c2f4bf4e17c0fc657a8d6c7a9791fd8a8832c613)

The code

```
App.AboutRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return App.Person.find();
  }
}); 

App.Person.FIXTURES = [
 {
   id:1,
   name: 'Tom'
 },
 {
   id: 2,
   name: 'Giorgio'
 },
 {
   id: 3,
   name: 'Laura'
 }
];

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="about">
  <ul>
    {{#each person in model}}
      <li>{{person.name}}</li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
  About 
</script>



App.AboutRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return App.Person.find();
  }
})
```

How can i make my models working again with the about view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why you have 2 App.About.Route but try this

```
App.AboutRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find('person');
  }
})
```